# Soundcloud - Joining / Mixing samples via the API

Tags: api, merge, soundcloud

Anyone know if it is possible to submit a sequence of samples to Soundcloud to be compiled as one continuous file?

Even better, can samples be mixed & merged together via the API.

This would be great, but realise it may not be possible.

Just wondering?

Cheers

Mike

Comment: Take a look at http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the comment but need an web service.

Comment: Sounds like an opening in the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately we do not offer such functionality at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, just thought i'd check.

Comment: You could do something with the Web Audio API, but it would take some work. See an example: http://audiojedit.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's great, I think that it is one way to go, but wondering if that browser support may not be up to it yet.